# Is this article correct about leveraged tokens?

Tags: investing, trading, margin, leverage

[In this article](https://www.fool.com/the-ascent/cryptocurrency/articles/6-things-to-know-before-you-buy-leveraged-tokens/), it says the following:

> Let's say you're interested in buying Bitcoin, so you purchase $100 of it. After a day, the price has increased by 10%, and your investment is worth $110. But the next day, the price decreases by 10%, which would be an $11 drop. Your investment would be worth $99.
>
> What if you invested $100 in a leveraged token that tripled Bitcoin's returns? That would turn the 10% increase on day one into a 30% increase, bringing your investment up to $130. But it would also result in a 30% drop on day two, costing you $39 and leaving you with $91. A minor loss on a normal crypto purchase becomes a much bigger loss on a leveraged token.

I tried to recalculate it, but got different results:

- You start with $100 (which is $300 on the "margin account")
- The price goes up 10%, you get $130 ($300+($300*0.1)=$330 on the margin account)
- The price goes down 10%, you get $97 ($330-($330*0.1)=$297 on the margin account)

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize that it reinvests daily and that's how $91 comes out.

- Start with $100 ($300 on the margin account)
- The price goes up 10%, you have $100 + ($30 * 0.1) = $130 ($300 + ($300 * 0.1) = $330 on the margin account)
- Reinvest the profit ($390 on the margin account)
- The price goes down 10%, you have $130 - ($390 * 0.1) = $91 ($390 - ($390 * 0.1) = $351 on the margin account)

Comment: Put another way: 'Reinvests daily' = 'extends the loan to the full 300% of the new account balance and puts those funds back into the asset'.